# Finding a minimum/maximum weight Steiner tree

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree

I asked this question on reddit, but haven't converged on a solution yet.  Since many of my searches bring me to Stack Overflow, I decided I would give this a try.  Here is a simple formulation of my problem:

Given a weighted undirected graph G(V,E,w) and a subset of vertices S in G, find the min/max weight tree that spans S.  Adding vertices is not allowed.  An extension of the basic model is adding edges with 0 weight, and vertices that must be excluded.  This seems similar to the question asked here:

[Algorithm to find minimum spanning tree of chosen vertices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146710/algorithm-to-find-minimum-spanning-tree-of-chosen-vertices)

There is also more insight into what values the edges can take.  Each edge is actually a correlation probability, which I can encode in several ways, so the main questions I want to ask the graph are:

1. Given k vertices that must be connected, what are the top X min/max spanning trees that connect them, and what vertices do they pass through?  As I understand it, this is the same question as asking the graph what is the highest probability of connecting all of the k vertices.
2. Getting more vague, is there a logical way to cluster the nodes?

As for implementation, I have the boost libraries installed, and once I get the framework rolling on this problem, I can deal with how to multi-thread it (if appropriate), what kind of graph to use, and how to store/cache the data, since the number of vertices and edges is going to be quite large.

**Update**
Looking at the problem I am trying to solve, it makes sense that it would be NP-complete.  The real world problem that I am trying to solve involves medical diagnoses; specifically when the medical community is working on a problem with a specific idea in mind, and they need to take a step back and reconsider how they got there.  What I want from the program I am trying to design is:

- Given several conditions, tests, symptoms, age, gender, season, confirmed diagnosis, timeline, how can you relate them?  What cells/tissues/organs/systems are touched?  Are they even related?
- Along with the defined groups that conditions/symptoms can belong to, is there a way to logically group the conditions/symptoms?

**Example**
Flu-like symptoms, red eyes, early pneumonia, and some of the signs of diabetes.  Is there a way to relate all of the symptoms?  Are there some tests that could be done to make it easier to determine?  What systems are involved?

It just seemed natural to try and map this to a graph, or several graphs, and use probabilities as the correlation between different symptoms/conditions.

Comment: This problem is NP-hard, so there is no known efficient algorithm for it.  You will probably have to brute-force search for the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is what I came up with as well.  Any ideas on how to parallelize it efficiently?  What implementation of a graph do you think is best; probably the adjacency matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen models for your problem that were mostly based on Bayesian inference and fuzzy logic. Bayesian inference networks express the relation between causes and effects e.g. smoking and lung cancer. Look [here](http://www.autonlab.org/tutorials/bayesinf05.pdf) for a quick tutorial. You can apply fuzzy logic to that modelling to try to take into account the variablility in real life (as not everyone gets lung cancer).

Comment: This is sort of the direction that I was headed, except that I am looking a bit at Markov fields, and hidden Markov models.  Mostly I want to preserve the correlation between variables, but be able to move along the graph in an undirected manner.  I'm not necessarily looking for a cause/effect relationship, but a correlation, possibly with hidden data.