# Correlation Network Implementation

Tags: algorithm, boost, graph, graph-algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree

I have been working on my graph/network problem, and I think I finally know what I want to do.  Now that I am getting into the implementation, I am having issues deciding what libraries to use.  The graph itself is pretty simple, each node is labeled by a string, and each each is a probability/correlation coefficient between the two nodes(variables), and is undirected.  The operations that I want to perform on the graph are:

- Inserting new nodes/edges (fast)
- Finding the all pairs shortest (1/probability) path, and remembering the nodes in the path - probably Johnson's algorithm
- Constructing the minimum weight Steiner tree for k specific vertices

  - Use Johnson's algorithm to build shortest paths
  - Iterating over the current nodes in the path p, find the shortest route to the remaining nodes in k
- Looking at the mean degree of the graph
- Evaluating the betweenness of the nodes
- Getting the clustering coefficients
- Finding the modularity of the graph

For many of these, I want to compare the result to the Erdos-Renyi model, testing against it as a null hypothesis.  Also, being able to be able to use the statistical mechanics definitions via a Markov Field would be helpful, as then I could calculate correlations between two nodes that are not identical, and ask the graph questions about the entropy, etc.  So a good mapping onto a Markov field library of some sort would be useful too.

The crux of the problem at the moment is that I am trying to find a C++ library to work in.  I have taken a look at R, but I want something that is going to be more robust and faster.  The three libraries that I am considering are:

- LEMON

  - Easy to use and install
  - Straightforward documentation
  - Has some of the functions I want already
  - Dynamically creating a graph from reading in a text file, and making sure there are no duplicate nodes, is a nightmare that I have not been able to figure out
- Boost Graph Library

  - Intractable, arcane definitions for objects, and how to use them
  - Documentation does not match what the code does, necessarily
  - Does have many of the algorithms that I want, as well as a very easy way to create a graph from a text file
- MultiThreaded Graph Library

  - Parallelism already incorporated
  - Reads easier than the BGL
  - Not as many functions
  - Still arcane

Further down the road, I envision the graph living on a distributed network, with distributed storage (hadoop or something).  I suspect that the whole graph will not fit into memory, and so I will have to come up with a caching scenario to look at parts of the graph.

What library would people suggest for the problem that I described?  Would it be better to just use the BGL, and write my own functions?  What about the multi-threaded version?  Are there any libraries that lend themselves more readily to the type of work I want to do, especially the quantities I want to compute?

[Original Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846335/finding-a-minimum-maximum-weight-steiner-tree)

Thanks!

**Edit1**
So I am seriously frustrated by the BGL.  I have an adjacency list graph, and I want to run my own version of the Johnson's (or Floyd's, at this point, I am not picky) on the graph, and return the Distance Matrix for me to look at.  Except that I can't get it to work.  Here is my full code implementation thus far:

```
using namespace boost;

int main()
{
//Read in the file
std::ifstream datafile("stuff");
if (!datafile)
{
    std::cerr << "No Stuff file" << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

//Build the graph
typedef adjacency_list < vecS, vecS, undirectedS, property < vertex_name_t,
    std::string >, property < edge_weight_t, double > > Graph;
Graph g;

//Build the two properties we want, string and double
//Note, you have to nest properties for more
typedef property_map< Graph, vertex_index_t >::type vertex_index_map_t;
vertex_index_map_t vertex_index_map = get(vertex_index, g);
typedef property_map < Graph, vertex_name_t >::type name_map_t;
name_map_t name_map = get(vertex_name, g);
typedef property_map < Graph, edge_weight_t >::type probability_map_t;
probability_map_t probability = get(edge_weight, g);

//Map of of the vertices by string
typedef graph_traits < Graph >::vertex_descriptor Vertex;
typedef std::map < std::string, Vertex > NameVertexMap;
NameVertexMap AllNodes;

//Load the file into the graph
for (std::string line; std::getline(datafile, line);)
{
    char_delimiters_separator < char >sep(false, "", ";");
    tokenizer <> line_toks(line, sep);
    tokenizer <>::iterator i = line_toks.begin();
    std::string conditionA = *i++;
    NameVertexMap::iterator pos;
    bool inserted;
    Vertex u, v;

    boost::tie(pos, inserted) = AllNodes.insert(std::make_pair(conditionA, Vertex()));
    if (inserted)
    {
        u = add_vertex(g);
        name_map[u] = conditionA;
        pos->second = u;
    }
    else
    {
        u = pos->second;
    }

    std::string correlation = *i++;
    std::istringstream incorrelation(correlation);
    double correlate;
    incorrelation >> correlate;

    boost::tie(pos, inserted) = AllNodes.insert(std::make_pair(*i, Vertex()));
    if (inserted) {
        v = add_vertex(g);
        name_map[v] = *i;
        pos->second = v;
    }
    else
    {
        v = pos->second;
    }

    graph_traits < Graph >::edge_descriptor e;
    boost::tie(e, inserted) = add_edge(u, v, g);
    if (inserted)
        probability[e] = 1.0/correlate;
}

typedef boost::graph_traits<Graph>::edge_iterator edge_iter;
std::pair<edge_iter, edge_iter> edgePair;
Vertex u, v;
for(edgePair = edges(g); edgePair.first != edgePair.second; ++edgePair.first)
{
    u = source(*edgePair.first, g);
    v = target(*edgePair.first, g);
    std::cout << "( " << vertex_index_map[u] << ":" << name_map[u] << ", ";
    std::cout << probability[*edgePair.first] << ", ";
    std::cout << vertex_index_map[v] << ":" << name_map[v] << " )" << std::endl;
}  
}
```

Where the input file is of the format NodeA;correlation;NodeB.  The code that I pasted above works, but I get into serious trouble when I attempt to include the johnson_all_pairs_shortest_paths functionality.  Really what I want is not only a DistanceMatrix D (which I cannot seem to construct correctly, I want it to be a square matrix of doubles double D[V][V], V = num_vertices(g), but it gives me back that I am not calling the function correctly), but also a list of the nodes that were taken along that path, similar to what the wiki article has for [Floyd's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) path reconstruction.  Should I just make the attempt to roll my own algorithm(s) for this problem, since I can't figure out if the functionality is there or not (not to mention how to make the function calls)? The documentation for the BGL is as obtuse as the implementation, so I don't really have any modern examples to go on.